# How do I move (not convert) a time into a new time zone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I have a DateTime `d` and a string `tz` that is a valid ActiveSupport::TimeZone key (e.g. "UTC", "Eastern Time (US & Canada)", "America/Chicago", etc.). How do I get a new DateTime d2 such that everything is the same, but the offset of `d2` now reflects that of the time zone corresponding to `tz`?

Note that I **do not want to convert** the time into the new time zone. I want a new DateTime with everything else equal, but with the offset different.

For example, if I have `d = <today @ 5:00 PM UTC>`, and `tz = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'`, what I want is `d2 = <today @ 5:00 PM -0600>`, *not* `d2 = <today @ 11:00 AM -0600>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `tz`, you can convert that to an offset as a fraction of a day:

```
offset = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(tz).utc_offset / 60 / 60 / 24.0
=> -0.25 # for 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

You can then pass this into `DateTime.civil` along with existing details from `d` to create the new object:

```
d2 = DateTime.civil(d.year, d.month, d.day, d.hour, d.min, d.sec, offset)
```

Comment: I'm really surprised there isn't a nicer way to do that, but looks like this is right. Perhaps someone could write a `DateTime.with_time_zone` to mirror `DateTime.in_time_zone`. Thanks!